# How to generate pdf with epydoc?

Tags: python, documentation, latex, epydoc

I am considering epydoc for the documentation of one module. It looks ok to me and is working fine when I am generating html document.

I would like to try to generate the documenation in the pdf format. I've just modified the 'output' setting in my config file.

Unfortunately, epydoc fails when generating the pdf file. The error is "Error: Error reading pstat file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'profile.out'"

it generates some tex files. I think that maybe I am missing latex but I am not very familliar with tex and latex. More over I am working on Windows.

What should be the next steps for making epydoc generating pdf file?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you used an existing conf file.

If you have a closer look inside, you will see an option `pstat: profile.out`. This options says that the file `profile.out` will be used to generate the call graph (see [doc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-reference.html)).

```
# The name of one or more pstat files (generated by the profile
# or hotshot module).  These are used to generate call graphs.
pstat: profile.out
```

You need to generate this file, by using the `profile`or `hotspot`module. For example, you can run your module by

```
python -m "profile" -o profile.out mymodule.py
```

(it is also possible to use `hotspot` or `cProfile`, that is much much faster than `profile`)

This should works (I hope so)